# Apache behind proxy: bypass Auth Basic for some ip

Tags: apache-httpd, authentication

I need bypass basic auth to some ip, Apache is 2.4 and is behind haproxy, i have inserti this into Document Root section:

```
<Directory /path/to/webroot>
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    <Limit GET>
        Require valid-user
    </Limit>
    Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

But don't work, apache is behind a proxy, it probably will not work because the ip which comes to apache is the proxy and not the client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable and configure [mod_remoteip](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html).  You proxy would set the original remote IP address in the header like `X-Forwarded-For` in HTTP requests.  Pass it to `RemoteIpHeader` directive placed outside `<Directory>`.

If mod_remoteip works correctly, original remote addresses passed by the proxy can be seen with `%a` in `LogFormat`.  You should first check this.

On Apache 2.4 `Satisfy` directive is [deprecated](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html).  And you'd better not complicate authz conditions by adding unnecessary `<Limit>`.

Try with the following configuration:

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For

<Directory /path/to/webroot>
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    Require valid-user
    Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Directory>
```

Comment: I have enabled mod_remoteip and add the line to apache2.conf but don't work, the proxy is set correctly, if i add `%{X-Forwarded-For}i`in the `LogFormat` section, i see the correct external ip on the logs

Comment: Updated.  Please check if `%a` in `LogFormat` also tells original remote addresses.

Comment: Yes, if i place `%a` i have the right ip to logs, i have edit my apache exactly like you have type but don't ask password when access with another ip not trusted

Comment: Well, just a guess, but have you restarted your browser?  It might hold credentials you entered earlier in the session.

Comment: Yes, isn't no problem of cache, i never enter with password, is not in cache

Comment: Then you need to debug it yourself.  Comment out one of `Require` lines in turn to verify that each of them works separately.  Also consult [authn/authz howto](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html).  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, it work's, problem with my proxy for tests